# Telerik RadMaskedNumericInput mask

Tags: xaml, telerik, mask

I'm building a WPF application that uses the Telerik's RadMaskedNumericInput control. I never used this before, so I'm just exploring for the the moment.

The thing is, there is already a RadMaskedNumericInput control in our GUI that has the xaml you see below. I was asked to change the mask to make it more "flexible". I think what they meant was that the number of decimals should stay the same, but the users should be able to put any number they wanted, from 1.000 to 1000000etc.000. The mask in the xaml only allows numbers up to 999.999. How can I make it so that I can introduce any number I want, I mean, without a fixed size on the left side, but keeping the fixed size of the decimals?

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Margin ="15,15,15,0" Height="Auto" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.ColumnSpan="3">
                        <TextBlock Text="{lex:LocText AquaSafe.WPF.ClientControls.LagrangeanSimulator:Strings:strConstantFlow}" Margin="0 0 0 5"/>
                        <telerik:RadMaskedNumericInput Value="{Binding DefaultValueFlow, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, NotifyOnValidationError=True}"
                            Validation.ErrorTemplate="{StaticResource VerticalErrorTemplate}"
                            Mask="#3.3" Height="30" Width="150" telerik:StyleManager.Theme="Metro" />
                    </StackPanel>
```

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this question?

Answer (score 0):

go through this documentation which describes the different mask values.

http://www.telerik.com/help/wpf/radmaskedinput-features-mask-tokens.html

hope this help you.